# Java script regular expression a bit confusing

Tags: javascript, regex

I am actually new to javascript and I'm trying to understand what went wrong with this code.
I have a function that accepts a `abc` as a parameter.

This regular expression was given to me by one of my colleges. I don't have any idea what it's doing.
Just wanted to understand what is the return statement here.

```js
(function(abc) {
  var match = abc.match(/(\d+).+?(\d+)/);
  return +match[2] + 1;
});
```

I think the match will contain digits in decimal format but not clear about it.
what will this return? Please let me understand this, will be a great help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: The regex `match` method returns an array of results. `+match[2]` takes the 3rd array element from that array, coerces it to a number, and then adds 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d+) - one or more digits (0-9)
.+?   - one or more periods (.)
(\d+) - one or more digits (0-9)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xhOfH8yYp4O1XJfp)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a snippet and debug it. Using provided example:

```js
function getDiskInfo(diskinfo) {
  var match = diskinfo.match(/(\d+).+?(\d+)/);
  return +match[2] + 1;
}

console.log(getDiskInfo('111.222'));
```

In this example, as described by @phuzi:

```
var match = ['111.222', '111', '222'];
```

After that your return statement cast your element with index = 2 to Number and increments it by one. So using my example the final result will be 223.

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)